# Spring Batch 4.0 ~ Code under JdbcCursorItemReader method doesn't run with @StepScope defined

Tags: spring-batch

I have a sql query defined in my batch job that needs to get input at runtime from the user.

I have the following item reader in my batch job defined as follows

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<QueryCount> queryCountItemReader() throws Exception {

    ListPreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter = new ListPreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
            pstmt.setString(1, "#{jobparameters[fromDate]}");
            pstmt.setString(2, "#{jobparameters[toDate]}");
            pstmt.setString(3, "#{jobparameters[fromDate]}");
            pstmt.setString(4, "#{jobparameters[toDate]}");
            pstmt.setString(5, "#{jobparameters[fromDate]}");
            pstmt.setString(6, "#{jobparameters[toDate]}");
            pstmt.setString(7, "#{jobparameters[eventType]}");
            pstmt.setString(8, "#{jobparameters[businessUnit]}");
            pstmt.setString(9, "#{jobparameters[deviceCategory]}");
            pstmt.setString(10, "#{jobparameters[numberOfSearchIds]}");
        }
    };

    JdbcCursorItemReader<QueryCount> queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(sqlQuery);
    queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new QueryCountMapper());
    queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(preparedStatementSetter);

    int counter = 0;
    ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();

    queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.open(executionContext);

    try {

        QueryCount queryCount;

        while ((queryCount = queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.read()) != null) {

            System.out.println(queryCount.toString());

            counter++;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader.close();
    }

    return queryCountJdbcCursorItemReader;
}
```

I am sending in the job parameters from my application class as follows

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("fromDate", "20180410")
                .addString("toDate", "20180410")
                .addString("eventType", "WEB")
                .addString("businessUnit", "UPT")
                .addString("numberOfSearchIds", "10")
                .toJobParameters();

        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

The issue is, when I run my batch job the code inside the queryCountItemReader() method is never executed and the job completes with no errors. Essentially the sql query I am trying to run never executes. If I remove the @StepScope annotation the code will then run but fail with an error since it is enable to bind the parameters sent in from the application class to the sql query. I realize that @StepScope is necessary to use job parameters but why doesn't the code in my method execute?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding `@EnableBatchProcessing` & `@EnableAutoConfiguration`annotations and changing the item reader method definition as follows,

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<QueryCount> queryCountItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['fromDate']}") String fromDate,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters['toDate']}") String toDate,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters['eventType']}") String eventType,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters['businessUnit']}") String businessUnit,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters['deviceCategory']}") String deviceCategory,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters['numberOfSearchIds']}") String numberOfSearchIds) throws Exception {
```